# Get records after a certain record (id) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, record

I want to get records after a certain record, say `id` is 4.
Actually I want to show posts based on likes with pagination.

So I sorted result by likes.
But I don't know how to get the next records based on `id`.

Here is my code

```
SELECT urp.* , likes
FROM user_related_posts urp
JOIN (
    SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) AS likes
    FROM post_likes
    WHERE STATUS =1
    GROUP BY post_id
    ) v ON urp.post_id = v.post_id
GROUP BY post_id
ORDER BY likes DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Sorry I don't put image, I don't have enough credentials.

What here doing is when I order with likes, ids are unsorted,
but I want records based on `id`.
[image: Image Link]

[image: Image Link]

Comment: you want only id =4 record?

Comment: no i want records after id=4

Comment: can you provide above sql result and expecting result.

Comment: You need something like [`ROW_NUMBER()` solutions in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1895110/4519059) ;).

Comment: i add the image please at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LIMIT so that you can retrieve it like pagination

Answer (score 0):

You can use `date_created` in your query.

```
SELECT        *
FROM            post_likes
WHERE        (date_created >
                             (SELECT        date_created
                               FROM            post_likes AS p1
                               WHERE        (id= 4)))
```

**Note** :

I have not added the entire code.Please use the code and edit as your requirement.